# How to cancel touches in all subviews?

Tags: iphone

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by cancel touches?

Comment: can you explaine... what you want to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `hitTest:withEvent:` in `UIView` to always return self and it will no longer pass touch events to subviews.

Answer (score 1):

```
someSubview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```